# Use PHP to get xls(Excel files) PHPOffice PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpoffice

Hy guys.

Thank you for your help. The answers in this forum are great!

In my site, i want to see the content from a xls Excel Spreadsheet. 
After long searching i found this Project:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/

I get the classes and tried it. Works great!

It works so good, that i can't believe, that it is free.
Is it free to use?

at the top of my site, i got this error massage:
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in test/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE.php on line 288

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the error, I replaced continue by continue 2 and it resolved the error

Answer (score 2):

about the first question (if it's free).

Since the author of repository it's under of GNU (in the repo has the link, but if you didn't read it or see it here's -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/master/license.md).

Second, about your `continue 2` error, you need check first which version of PHP you're running, those `continues` issues are very frequently in some old libraries (mainly this one the last significant update was 6 years ago).

If you check the issues of Github you'll see there's an exact bug issue opened about what you're asking here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/436.

Ok, but what's the solution?!

Well, you have 2 simples solutions:

1 - Use another library or create yours.
2 - Try to fix the issue.

Particularly if I was you I chose the first, and now when you get some new library/plugin I strongly suggest you before download it check the issues in the repository to avoid has those weird bugs in your system.

If you anyway choose for some reason keep going with this one, try to fix it and open a PR.

As per documentation, you can fix easily https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php and just compile again the library and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Think this:

For `break` and `continue`, a `switch` is like a loop, that runs only once. `break` leaves every loop, and switch-loop too.

`continue` starts the next iteration of a loop. Because `switch` runs only once, it terminate the switch-loop.

To restart or leave outer loops (this includes outer `switch`too) use a positive integer behind `break` and `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are using old PHP version. Try updating it to 7.3+

And go look here - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break/

They have the same problem as you.

Alsoo, on github there is information that repo is deprecated.
Maybe use this ? - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet